# Facing problems passing env files to docker container using Gitlab Ci/Cd for Amazon ECS

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs

I have scanned every possible article on the internet on this topic since yesterday, but I am just not able to figure out how to pass my env files onto the container running on Gitlab.

I am working on NodeJs app using Gitlab Ci/CD, DockerFile, and Amazon ECS for deploying my project onto the service. I have 3 different env files for 3 different environments i.e., prod, staging and the dev.

here is my **.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
include:
  - template: AWS/Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci.yml
```

**Dockerfile** contents are as below:

```
FROM node:16 

WORKDIR /.

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json   
COPY ./package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# 
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the server

CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

the .env files are in the local bin folder and each file has many env variables inside:

[image]

I cannot seem to pass these items while pipeline builds, and it results in failure. Not only that but I am not even able to create my ECS service because app is not able to bootstrap correctly on the cluster because of the missing env files.

**What I tried:**

Almost everything. To summarize here are the steps I followed:

- I Read about docker compose on how to import env files based on dev, prod or stag environment but in my case, I don't know how to use docker compose for ECS as I have manually done my configuration on Amazon ECS by creating Task definitions, Clusters and even tried running demo tasks by myself. Now all I have to do is configure ci/cd via gitlab.
- Added a base docker-compose to my app:

[image]

but not able to modify `.gitlab-ci.yml` to run docker-compose in some way, as I am simply including Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci template as shown above. If I write my own gitlab-ci then it will not auto build my changes once I push on the branch.

- I read about Deploying on ECS cluster using Gitlab Ci/Cd on their official webpage but it is very generic use case and explains nothing on env files.

Since I am stuck on this since yesterday, it is getting very exhausting for me to fully understand how to make this work. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your setup is hard to exactly tell how you are using GitLab - but everything seems to point that you are making use of AutoDevops so I'll try to help.

The template you are importing, it's using [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml) other CI file which is in charge of building the Docker image. In this template, the `build.sh` is executed and that file is hosted in another GitLab project, visible [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/-/blob/master/src/build.sh).

Given that everything is provided by GitLab and it's a bit opaque for the end user, you have to dig into the AutoDevops config [variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/cicd_variables.html) to know how to pass custom variables to the build job.

Now coming into the Docker specifics, you can use the arg `-env-file` but only with Docker Compose so that won't work here. If you have only a few variables to add, you can add them in the `AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS` variable to have them forwarded to the Docker container:

```
include:
  - template: AWS/Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS: --build-arg=YOUR_VARIABLE=foobar
```

That setup is not ideal if you have lots of env vars so you can also add the `.env` file on your Docker image:

```
...

COPY env.dev .
RUN source env.dev

...
```

Hope this helps or guides you in the correct direction!

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I am making use of AutoDevops. I just have a question here, as a dev I would only push my changes on a branch e.g., main, staging or dev and the build process will be automatically triggered by Gitlab ci/cd so from where exactly it will copy the contents from env.dev with commands `COPY env.dev .` and `RUN source env.dev`?  Will the contents be copied from my local setup?

Also, how will I use different env file based on my changes getting committed to dev, prod or staging branch in this scenario?

Comment: The latter solution would expect you to have the `.env` files stored in your repo - which is not ideal - so you can have them copied to the container afterwards. You can even generate it on the fly and pass it down to the `build` job but that will require a bit more effort. With that approach you can distinguish between environments easily too.
As you're not creating your own pipeline and using a provided template, it may not be a 100% fit for your use-case so perhaps that's something to consider for your scenario

Comment: `You can even generate it on the fly and pass it down to the build job` - I wanted to have something of this sort but since I am including the built in template `Deploy-ECS.gitlab-ci` I guess I may not be able to use separate other build commands.